# Rails - How Do I Nest Comments - Polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, polymorphism

For my application, I have Projects. I have used Polymorphism to build a model called "Newcomment" for comments made on these Projects. I followed this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).  This works great.

But now, I want to build comments on top of comments. I tried following this tutorial (http://kconrails.com/2010/10/23/nested-comments-in-ruby-on-rails-1-models/) and (http://kconrails.com/2011/01/26/nested-comments-in-ruby-on-rails-controllers-and-views/). I put a form for comments in each comment that I render. I also adjusted the newcomment.rb model, so that newcomment `has_many newcomments` and the routes.rb file.

**Question: Right now, when I make a comment in the form of each comment, it posts as a comment to the project and not as a response to a specific comment. How would I adjust my code so that I can have comments for comments?**

**newcomment.rb**

```
class Newcomment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :newcomments, :as => :commentable

  belongs_to :user

  scope :newest, order("created_at desc")

  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

**newcomments_controller.rb**

```
class NewcommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_commentable
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

def create
    @newcomment = @commentable.newcomments.new(params[:newcomment])

    if @newcomment.save
      redirect_to comments_project_path(@commentable), notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
end

def destroy
    if current_user.try(:admin?)
        @newcomment = Newcomment.find(params[:id])
        @commentable = @newcomment.commentable
        @newcomment.destroy

        if @newcomment.destroy
            redirect_to comments_url, notice: "Comment deleted."
        end
    else
        @newcomment = Newcomment.find(params[:id])
        @commentable = @newcomment.commentable
        @newcomment.destroy

        if @newcomment.destroy
           redirect_to comments_project_path(@commentable), notice: "Comment deleted."
        end
    end
end

private
    def load_commentable
            resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
            @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :projects do
    resources :newcomments do
      resources :newcomments
    end
end
```

**view/projects/_comments.html.erb**

```
<%= render @newcomments %>
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def comments
    @commentable = @project
    @newcomments = @commentable.newcomments.newest.page(params[:comments_page]).per_page(10)
    @newcomment = Newcomment.new
end
```

**view/newcomments/_newcomment.html.erb**

```
<div class="comments"> 
    <%= link_to newcomment.user.name %></strong>
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(newcomment.created_at) %> ago
    <%= newcomment.content %>
</div>

<span class="comment">
    <%= form_for [@commentable, @newcomment] do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 3, :class => "span8" %>
      </div>

      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :class => "btn btn-header" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    <% unless newcomment.newcomments.empty? %>
       <%= render @newcomments %>
    <% end %>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need, instead of working on it from a scrap, is: https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the routes like this

```
resources :newcomments do
  resources :newcomments
end
```

which is a bad smell and we need to fix. In some of our projects, we are also using https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading and it's good.